# How to change this while loop to a for loop in C?

Tags: c, robotics

This code is for making a robot in a simulator move in specific paths using C. The code of the ***while loop*** is where I need to make changes, I was wondering how to change the code so that the robot moves in a straight line and stop, and how to use 'timed distance' to make it move in a triangle.

```
while (1) {
    sprintf(buf, "M LR 60 -60\n");
    write(sock, buf, strlen(buf));
    memset(buf, 0, 80);
    read(sock, buf, 80);
}
```

`M LR` is the name for the Left and Right motors in the robot(the robot has two motors that make it move) and 60 and -60 are their speeds. This code makes the robot spin.

The full code is in this link: [[C Robot](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Wv8afdcxeNp9wT-uidCjOILHOaLutXi37a4iK-8HXEg/edit?usp=sharing)]

How to make this code work?

```
int k = 1;

for (k = 1; k < 3 ; k++){
    sprintf(buf, "M LR 20 10\n");
    write(sock, buf, strlen(buf));
    memset(buf, 0, 80);
    read(sock, buf, 80);
}

for (k=3; k > 3; k++) {
    sprintf(buf, "M LR 0 0\n");
    write(sock, buf, strlen(buf));
    memset(buf, 0, 80);
    read(sock, buf, 80);
}
```

Comment: Your title really doesn't match what your question says.

Comment: It seems that your question title is incorrect. Do you just want to replace the while loop with a different construct that does that same thing or do you want to achieve something completely different?!

Comment: With your current for loop : `for (k = 3; k > 3; k++)` => since k is assigned 3 just before entering the loop, the test `k > 3` is false right from the beginning and the loop is simply skipped. Moreover, since the numbers after the "M LR" sequence give the speed to apply to the motors, I guess you should set positive values if you want your robot to move.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(;;) {
    sprintf(buf, "M LR 60 -60\n");
    write(sock, buf, strlen(buf));
    memset(buf, 0, 80);
    read(sock, buf, 80);
}
```

I see no reason to do this.

Comment: Some compilers (e.g. MSVC++) will warn `while (1)`, but not `for(;;)`.

Comment: int k = 1;
    for (k = 1; k < 3 ; k++){
         sprintf(buf, "M LR 20 10\n");
         write(sock, buf, strlen(buf));
         memset(buf, 0, 80);
         read(sock, buf, 80);
                    }
    for (k=3; k > 3; k++) {
            sprintf(buf, "M LR 0 0\n");
            write(sock, buf, strlen(buf));
            memset(buf, 0, 80);
            read(sock, buf, 80);
        }

Comment: `while(1)` is a legal construct in C though.. why does it warn?

Comment: Because the proper way to write an infinite loop is `for(;;)`. (Seriously, the reason probably is that the compiler writers thought one might accidentally mistype the condition, so it's safer to warn. Similar to the warning for the - also legal - `if (x = y)`.)

Comment: @DanielFischer that's the problem with MSVC, it thinks programmers are notoriously lazy.. while in reality most are quite attentive while programming(which is why I sometimes like GCC, you can shoot yourself.. no strings attached)